# Is it true that $x \int_{x}^{\infty} f_{X}(t) d t \leq \int_{x}^{\infty} t f_{X}(t) d t $?

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose $f(x) \ge 0$. The following should be true
$$ x \int_{x}^{\infty} f_{X}(t) d t \leq \int_{x}^{\infty} t f_{X}(t) d t $$
but I cannot prove it (it seems to me that when $x$ is arbitrary large and for such value $f(x)$ is arbitrarily small, the left hand side should be larger...)

Comment: You have a good answer, but to emphasize: Inequalities, like equations, tend to be simpler to work with when one side is $0$. That leads us to rearrange by subtracting the left side from the right, yielding the equivalent$$0 \leq \int_{x}^{\infty}(t - x)f_{X}(t)\, dt).$$This is clear since the integrand is non-negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $t f_X(t) \geq x f_X(t)$ for $t \geq x$. Then $\int_x^\infty t f_X(t) dt \geq \int_x^\infty x f_X(t) dt$